# How to compress lists before writing them to a JSON

Tags: python

An important thing to add (after starting to receive answers): I cannot change the original dictionary, I need to be able to deal with a list that is `[0.2] * 100000`...

It is possible to also get large lists that are not single-valued lists, but I am ok with not dealing with them and leaving them as lists.

I have the following (simplied) issue: I have a list which is created using: `[0.2] * 100000`.

I am taking this list and saving it to a file by first converting it into a JSON using `json.dump(a)`

The file becomes huge as the list contains 100000 values. Is there any simple way to compress the list? Ideally I would want the file to simply have `[0.2] * 100000`

Just to give the complete story, the original use-case is a dictionary that contains many items, some of which are lists. I want to save this dictionary as a "config file" using `json.dump(config, , sort_keys=False, indent=4)`

Ideally I would want the output file to look something like:

```
config = {
    'key1' = [0.2] * 10000,
    'key2' = 0.3,
    'key3' = {
        'subkey1' = [0.0] * 100,
        'subkey2' = 'ya ba da bi do',
    },
    'key4' = 'Wubba Lubba Dub Dub'
},
```

and not:

```
config = {
    'key1' = [
          0.2,
          0.2,
          0.2,
          0.2,
          0.2,
          0.2,
          0.2,
          ...
```

Comment: You could store the multiplier in a second variable, like `key1_mult: 10000`

Comment: Could that list realistically have 100k different values? Or is it always a base figure that's repeated N times?

Comment: Check out the JSON data types: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp As a possible solution you could define a 'key1_value' as 0.2 and a 'key1_factor' as 100000 and maybe 'key1_type' as 'list'. Interpreting this would be the job of the recipient.

Comment: Edited my question to indicate that I cannot change the way that the original data is stored.

Comment: @JonClements - It can have multiple values, but in this case I am ok with not compressing the resulting file. I'll be happy with dealing just with this specific cases which are single-valued lists.

Comment: How about just (g/b)zipping the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution, in the end, was to just use RegEx, as this is string manipulations...

I'm attaching my complete code, this does exactly as I wanted in the original post, plus more: It also turns all lists in single liner.

```
    # The following pattern finds a list opening, an end of line, and a numeric value
    # It then removes the end of line in the middle
    pattern = r"\[\n\s+(?P<value>\d)"
    c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    while c is not None:
        config_json = re.sub(pattern, f"[{c.group('value')}", config_json, count=1)
        c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    # The following pattern finds a numeric value, an end of line and a list closing
    # It then removes the end of line in the middle
    pattern = r"(?P<value>\d)\n\s+\]"
    c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    while c is not None:
        config_json = re.sub(pattern, f"{c.group('value')}]", config_json, count=1)
        c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    # The following pattern finds a numeric value, a comma, an end of line and
    # another numeric value
    # It then removes the end of line in the middle
    pattern = r"(?P<value1>\d),\n\s+(?P<value2>\d)"
    c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    while c is not None:
        config_json = re.sub(
            pattern, f"{c.group('value1')}, {c.group('value2')}", config_json, count=1
        )
        c = re.search(pattern, config_json)
    # After this, the lists have been be transformed to be one liners

    # The following pattern find multiple consecutive numeric value, separated by commas
    # It replaces them by a single value list multiplied by the number of occurrences
    pattern = (
        r"(?P<start>\[|, )(?P<value>\d(?P<float>.\d)?)(, (?P=value))+(?P<end>\]|, )"
    )
    c = re.search(pattern, config_json)

    while c is not None:
        dist = 5 if c.group("float") is not None else 3
        extra = len(c.group("start")) + len(c.group("end"))
        start_str = "[" if c.group("start") == "[" else "] + ["
        end_str = "" if c.group("end") == "]" else " + ["
        n_of_occurrences = int((c.end() - c.start() - extra - dist + 2) / dist + 1)
        config_json = re.sub(
            pattern,
            f"{start_str}{c.group('value')}] * {n_of_occurrences}{end_str}",
            config_json,
            count=1,
        )
        c = re.search(pattern, config_json)
```

While this is not the most elegant solution, it works.

Answer (score 0):

save it as a list, like

```
'key1':[0.2, 10000],
```

and uncompress it as:

```
[config['key1'][0]]*config['key1'][1]
```

or for better readability:

```
'key1' : {'val':0.2,'multiplier':10000},
```

and use like:

```
[config['key1']['val']]*config['key1']['multiplier']
```

Comment: Edited my question to indicate that I cannot change the way that the original data is stored.

Comment: so how is it stored? if it's just the long list, then you can load it as a long list, what's the issue

Comment: That the resulting file is a million lines long, which makes readability very hard, and causes the file size to be huge

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could consider storing the config file in compressed format.

For example:

```
import zlib
import ast

d = {'key1': [0.2] * 100000}

cb = zlib.compress(str(d).encode())

with open('config.zip', 'wb') as config:
    config.write(cb)

with open('config.zip', 'rb') as config:
    cd = zlib.decompress(config.read())
    e = ast.literal_eval(cd.decode())
    assert e == d
```

In this example, the archive is a mere 772 bytes